# Killing processes from list of executable names in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, process, kill

I've got a PowerShell function that's returning a list of executable names (with the file extension), and I'm trying to kill any of these if they are running, but not having much success. Here's the command I'm using:

```
Get-Executable-Names `
| where { $_ -match ".exe" } `
| foreach { $_ -replace ".exe" } `
| foreach { ps $_ } `
| kill
```

If I store the output of Get-Executable-Names in a variable and display its contents, it shows up as:

```
Path
----
A.exe
B.exe
C.exe
```

PowerShell is reporting this error:

> Get-Process : Cannot find a process with the name "@{Path=A}". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again. 
>   + $Get-Executable-Names | where { $_ -match ".exe" } | foreach { $_ -replace ".exe" } | foreach { ps <<<<  $_ } | kill 
>   + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (@{Path=A}:String) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException

It seems that the `-replace` operation changes the pipe data to the following format:

```
@(Path=A)
@(Path=B)
@(Path=C)
```

which I don't understand. I'm sure I'm just misunderstanding PowerShell's object model here, but what am I overlooking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following just after the call to GetExecutableNames

```
%{ $_.Path }
```

Full answer

```
Get-Executable-Names 
| where { $_ -match ".exe" } 
| %{ $_.Path }
| %{ $_ -replace ".exe" } 
| %{ ps $_ } 
| kill
```

Comment: To explain what was going on, Get-Executable-Names (you should remove the last dash) is returning an array of hashtables.  When you convert a hashtable to a string (which is needed for -replace), you get the code that represents the hashtable.